# Execute Javascript function between two Backing bean methods

Tags: jsf, primefaces, websocket

I'm writing a JSF web application who follow the next steps:

1. Read a number from an input text
2. Look for the number in a legacy system
3. Generate a message and send It to a websocket
4. Get the response from the websocket
5. Store the result in a database

All of these steps must be executed in a single event, all of these tasks are executed in a backing bean, the problem is to execute the javascript to call the websocket and use this result to save it in the database.

I tried to use the `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("function();");` method, but this function **"Executes script after ajax request completes or on page load"** and I need to get the result to store it into the database and execute other operations.

**The question is, How and where can I handle these calls?**

NOTE:

I can see the following options, but I'm not sure how to implement them:

- Handle the calls using Javascript instead of backing bean, following the next tasks:

  1. from Javascript call a backing bean method to look the number and get the response.
  2. from Javascript get the result of the backing bean and send it to the websocket.
  3. from javascript receive the response from the websocket and call another backing bean to store the result into the database.
- Found a way to call a javascript function from the backing bean before the ajax request completes.
- Call the WebSocket in the Backing bean instead of using Javascript.

I hope you can help me, Thanks.

**----EDIT-----**

The websocket is running in localhost, in this way the web page handle a device in a local machine, so it must be executed in the Javascript side and the 3rd option is not possible.

Comment: The third one looks for me the most efficient and user friendly way. Just use a java client to call the web socket.

Comment: There's ambiguity in the question. What websocket exactly is it? The one served by same server or a 3rd party one?

Comment: The websocket is working with one standalone driver who uses a device in the local machine

Answer (score 0):

an option could be the following:

your xhtml should have 3 forms:

1. "User inputText/number form"
2. "websocket-Request Form" (hidden form/input)
3. "websocket response Data Form" (hidden form)

now you follow these steps:

1. A user submits input to your Bean (via ajax or commandActions ...etc)
2. bean-methode reads/validates that submitted data, then update value in form#2
3. Javascript/Jquery should listen on form#2/inputhidden value changed( then sends a wensocket request)
4. after recieving websocket response, update value inside form#3 and do autosubmit. now submitting this form calls an action methode in your bean which saves data to DB.